# Insert array into jsonb column from table postgresql

Tags: arrays, postgresql, aggregate-functions, sql-insert, jsonb

Im trying to create an insert statement into a jsonb column that looks like this

```
  "EmpNames": [
    {
      "id": "5680",
      "Surname": "James",
      "GivenName": "Julie",
      "MiddleName": "Jane",
    }
  ]
```

my sql statement is

```
select    'EmpNames',   
                      Array[
                               'Surname', surname
                               'GivenName', first_name,
                               'MiddleName', middle_name
                            ]::jsonb[]      
from stg.employees

invalid input syntax for type json
                               'Surname' Token "Surname" is invalid.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`jsonb_build_object()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) to create a json object and [`jsonb_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) to aggregate objects into a json array:

```sql
select
    jsonb_build_object(
        'EmpNames',
        jsonb_agg(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'id', id,
                'surname', surname,
                'first_name', first_name,
                'middle_name', middle_name
            )
        )
    )
from employees
```

Test it in [db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/SsIP8qUR)

If you want to create a json object for each `id` separately, the query doesn't require an aggregate:

```sql
select
    jsonb_build_object(
        'EmpNames',
        jsonb_build_array(
            jsonb_build_object(
                'id', id,
                'surname', surname,
                'first_name', first_name,
                'middle_name', middle_name
            )
        )
    )
from employees
```

[Db<>fiddle.](https://dbfiddle.uk/NKjJrSAs)

Comment: thanks @klin it worked..is there a way to write it so it comes out on separate rows for each person?